# Unable to run test project

Tags: java, android, junit

I am trying to set up a test project for my Android activity. I have been following the directions here: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-junit-testing/ and here: http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html.

When I run an android junit test, I get:

```
[2014-01-22 10:04:37 - AIR_ActivityTest] ------------------------------
[2014-01-22 10:04:37 - AIR_ActivityTest] Android Launch!
[2014-01-22 10:04:37 - AIR_ActivityTest] adb is running normally.
[2014-01-22 10:04:37 - AIR_ActivityTest] Performing android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner JUnit launch
[2014-01-22 10:04:44 - AIR_ActivityTest] Uploading AIR_ActivityTest.apk onto device 'TA5970MGMA'
[2014-01-22 10:04:44 - AIR_ActivityTest] Installing AIR_ActivityTest.apk...
[2014-01-22 10:04:45 - AIR_ActivityTest] Success!
[2014-01-22 10:04:45 - AIR_ActivityTest] Project dependency found, installing: AIR_Activity
[2014-01-22 10:04:45 - AIR_Activity] Uploading AIR_Activity.apk onto device 'TA5970MGMA'
[2014-01-22 10:04:46 - AIR_Activity] Installing AIR_Activity.apk...
[2014-01-22 10:04:49 - AIR_Activity] Success!
[2014-01-22 10:04:49 - AIR_ActivityTest] Launching instrumentation android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner on TA5970MGMA
[2014-01-22 10:04:49 - AIR_ActivityTest] Failed to launch test
```

I get the same error on the emulator and on a phone. I'm not seeing anything I think is probative in the logcat. I don't know where else to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the documentation here: http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html under section Junit is the following sentence:

Note that the Android testing API supports JUnit 3 code style, but not JUnit 4.

So, after wasting a whole day, I re-wrote my junit tests for junit 3 and now they're running on the device. :(